# Is this game too complicated?

Tags: opening

[Event "Rated Classical game"]
[Site "https://lichess.org/j457oH3R"]
[Date "2024.03.31"]
[White "healLan"]
[Black "LordSalva"]
[Result "1-0"]
[UTCDate "2024.03.31"]
[UTCTime "10:45:23"]
[WhiteElo "1467"]
[BlackElo "1427"]
[WhiteRatingDiff "+7"]
[BlackRatingDiff "-5"]
[Variant "Standard"]
[TimeControl "1800+15"]
[ECO "C70"]
[Opening "Ruy Lopez: Morphy Defense, Caro Variation"]
[Termination "Normal"]
[Annotator "lichess.org"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 b5 { C70 Ruy Lopez: Morphy Defense, Caro Variation } 5. Bb3 Nf6 6. O-O Nxe4 7. Re1 Nxf2 8. Kxf2 Bc5+ 9. Kf1 Qf6 10. Qe2 O-O 11. c3 d6 12. d4 Nxd4 13. cxd4 Bxd4 14. Be3 Bxe3 15. Bd5 Bb7 16. Bxb7 Rab8 17. Qxe3 Rxb7 18. Nc3 b4 19. Nd5 Qf5 20. Qe4 Qxe4 21. Rxe4 b3 22. axb3 Rxb3 23. Nxc7 Rxb2 24. Nxa6 Rfb8 25. Nxb8 Rxb8 26. Rd1 f6 27. Rxd6 Rb1+ 28. Ne1 { Black resigns. } 1-0